# Can I use an arduino as a LCD controller?

Tags: arduino, lcd, monitor, glcd

I saw [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B0uevXj1ARM) video where a person used a graphical LCD as a very rudimentary monitor for his computer using an Arduino... I was wondering whether it is possible to use an Arduino as a controller board for larger, proper LCDs (from laptops for example). If the Arduino doesn't have the processing capabilities, could you use, for example, an ESP32?

Comment: Yes \$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$

Comment: Make a wild guess as to how much RAM you would need and I think you will see that an Uno has no chance. I think a Due (or a blue pill) would be OK.

Comment: @Wouter van Ooijen Do you mean an Arduino Due? what about the STM32, as it's mentioned underneath? <a href="http://geek-mag.com/posts/255796">Here</a> is a link to a page that has the specs, do you think it's possible?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCak9gfJc8inCMZn1qxT39Gg) youtube channel. The videos are not extremely exciting, but they are extremely informative.

Comment: Yes, by Due I mean an Arduino Due, and a blue pill is a small (and cheap) STM32F103 board.

Comment: @Wouter van Ooijen So you are saying that the blue pill, which is about $3 on eBay, can do the same thing as a $30+ Arduino board??

Comment: On aliexpress, an Arduino Due is ~$20, a blue pill ~ $2. The due UC is somewhat better, but the STM in a blue pill is quite addequate (both cortex m3, 96k RAM versus 20k). But a blue pill lacks the USB converter, programming interface, DC-DC converter etc. of a due. And the due chip has much more IO pins.

Comment: @Wouter van Ooijen but the STM32 has a micro USB port... is that just for power?

Comment: It is connected to the USB pins of the chip itself, like the second USB port on an Arduino Due. Even with a bootloader, you can't use it for hands-off downloading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends probably:

- If the display memory should be sent completely by the Arduino during every 'refresh' rate, than no. The Arduino Uno has only 2 KB of memory and I doubt that is enough (depends on the resolution, e.g. 500 x 250 dots = 125,000 dots, assuming 1 bit per dot is 15 KB.
- If you only have to send the 'changes' than the Arduino is capable of doing so. This means probably that the LCD should have its own LCD driver.
- But even if you only need to send changes, than don't expect to be able to send fast videos. An Arduino has 16 MHz and depending on the video processing this might be too slow.

Comment: Okay, would an ESP32 cut it for a colour HD display? With proper refresh rate?

Comment: I don't know, I don't have experience with ESP32, I saw a video of STM32 versus Arduino and the STM32 is quite capable.